# How to filter rows in a .csv file where all the entries are 0 but without taking into consideration the first columns

Tags: csv, sed, awk, filtering, rows

I have a really large .csv file that looks like:

```
transcript_id,C3_MAR10,C4_APR10,CRL_2APR10,CRL_1_15JUL11,CRL_2_15JUL11,C1_OCT09,CRL_6OCT11,CRL_13DEC11,CRL_3DEC11,LRV6OCT11_A,LRV6OCT11_B 
comp1000201_c0_seq1,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
comp1000297_c0_seq1,0,7,0,0,0,0,15,7,0,0,0 
comp100036_c0_seq1,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0 
comp10003_c1_seq1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
comp100041_c0_seq1,0,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0 
comp100041_c0_seq2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0 
comp100041_c0_seq3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

And I want to filter/remove all the rows where all the values are 0 but without taking into account the first column. Of course I want the first column (my transcript ID's of my remaining rows) to be in my output file.

I was trying to use:

```
sed '/[^0,]/!d' file.csv > filtered_file.csv
```

But I am not filtering anything because all my first entries are ≠ to 0. I don't know how to say 'I only want to filter from column 2 to 12'.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){sum +=$i}if (sum>0) print $0;sum=0}' csv
```

Comment: While that would appear to work on the provided sample data, beware of things like `....0,2,-1,0,0,1,-2,....` where the sum may be zero even though there are non-zero elements... If you want to do it this way, then you should `sum += $i * $i` (or use `abs()` if your `awk` has it)...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i!=0){print $0;break}else continue;next}1' csv
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i!=0){print $0;break}else continue;next}1' csv
transcript_id,C3_MAR10,C4_APR10,CRL_2APR10,CRL_1_15JUL11,CRL_2_15JUL11,C1_OCT09,CRL_6OCT11,CRL_13DEC11,CRL_3DEC11,LRV6OCT11_A,LRV6OCT11_B 
comp1000201_c0_seq1,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
comp1000297_c0_seq1,0,7,0,0,0,0,15,7,0,0,0 
comp100036_c0_seq1,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0 
comp10003_c1_seq1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
comp100041_c0_seq1,0,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0 
comp100041_c0_seq2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0
```

Comment: It doesn't give me any error but when I do `wc -l filtered_file.csv` to count the number of rows this matches my initial number of rows.

Comment: Maybe that's because no rows had all 0s, so none of them were filtered.

Comment: @user2921271 Try the script at your sample data and notice the last row. You either dont have a row with all 0s or your input data is not a true representation of your question.

Comment: I did `head file.csv` and copy/pasted the head into my initial question, I cannot understand how my input data cannot be a true representation of my question. I also tried again and the number of rows of my filtered_file.csv in 307154 and the number of rows of my file.csv is 307153.

Comment: @user2921271 You are saying the script actually added a row to your data set? `:)` What `OS` are you on? `Linux`, `Solaris`, `Mac`? Does your file have windows `CR+LF`?

Comment: I am on MAC OS X 10.8.5. Can that be the problem?

Comment: @user2921271 I don't have a `bsd awk` handy at work, so I cant say for sure. But `bsd` does support `break` and `continue` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
awk '{f=$0;sub(/[^,]*/,"",f);gsub(/,/,"",f)} f' file
transcript_id,C3_MAR10,C4_APR10,CRL_2APR10,CRL_1_15JUL11,CRL_2_15JUL11,C1_OCT09,CRL_6OCT11,CRL_13DEC11,CRL_3DEC11,LRV6OCT11_A,LRV6OCT11_B
comp1000201_c0_seq1,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
comp1000297_c0_seq1,0,7,0,0,0,0,15,7,0,0,0
comp100036_c0_seq1,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0
comp10003_c1_seq1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
comp100041_c0_seq1,0,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0
comp100041_c0_seq2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0
```

It test if all value together are different than `0`